# screenshot of a video is coming with delay in mailbox

Tags: android

how to fix delay problem in taking snapshot from a video clip  in android studio  means i have to take an screenshot of a video which downloaded from the server side  & just after taking the screenshot I have to send it to the mail box , whats app etc. and these all things are working correctly but when I reach to the mailbox with screenshot than the screenshot of the video is coming with delay.